# Is my model returning logits or probabilities?

Tags: neural-network, classification, prediction, huggingface

I am training a neural network to do binary classification on some text data using BCEWithLogitsLoss() as my loss function using the following code:

```
# prep the data...

# Create the model
model = BigBirdForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    'google/bigbird-roberta-base'
    , num_labels=1
    , classifier_dropout = classifier_dropout
    , hidden_dropout_prob = hidden_dropout
)
model = model.to(device)
optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-5)
loss_fn = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()

# create accuracy metric
metric = load_metric("accuracy")

def compute_metrics(p):
    return metric.compute(predictions=p.predictions > 0.5, references=p.label_ids)

# Define TrainingArguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=model_save_path,
    num_train_epochs=5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=2,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=2,
    warmup_steps=1000,
    weight_decay=weight_decay,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    save_strategy="steps",
    eval_steps=33000,
    save_steps=5500,
    logging_steps=33000,
    load_best_model_at_end=False,
    save_total_limit=1,
    learning_rate=1e-5,
    fp16=True,
    report_to='none',
    seed=42
)

print(model_save_path)

def data_collector(features):
    batch = {}
    batch['input_ids'] = torch.stack([f[0] for f in features])
    batch['attention_mask'] = torch.stack([f[1] for f in features])
    batch['labels'] = torch.stack([f[2] for f in features])

    return batch

# Initialize Trainer
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=val_dataset,
    data_collator=data_collector,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)

if glob.glob(f"{model_save_path}/checkpoint*/pytorch_model.bin"):
    resume = True
else:
    resume = False

# train the model
logging.set_verbosity_error() 
trainer.train(resume_from_checkpoint = resume)

model_loaded = BigBirdForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(f"{model_save_path}/fullModel", local_files_only=True)
```

I used

```
def compute_metrics(p):
    return metric.compute(predictions=p.predictions > 0.5, references=p.label_ids)
```

as my accuracy measure, thinking the model would return probabilities. However, when I used trainer.predict() to return predictions for my test data, I realized that the values are sometimes below 0 or above 1 (min=-0.015726006, max=1.0713733).  So, this would imply model is actually outputting logits.  However, when I use the threshold of .5 on my logits the predictions seem fairly good (71% accuracy), but if I apply a sigmoid function to transform my logits to probabilities and use a threshold of .5 on those to create predictions, most of the predictions (96%) are 1, and the accuracy is only slightly better than chance.  This makes me wonder if my values are probabilites after all - and maybe they are sometimes outside the expected bounds due to rounding issues or something? Or is it just a coincidence that a threshold of .5 on my logits works much better than a threshold of 0 would?

Additional question - I was hoping to use probability scores as a measure of confidence. If my model is outputting logits, then the corresponding probability scores can't really be used the way I expected, given that most of my probabilities will be over .5 (even for those where the prediction is the negative case).  Is there a different transformation I could apply to my logits to get some more reasonably distributed confidence scores? Maybe just apply a sigmoid transform and then transform the probabilities to z-scores?